# Using Perl Selenium::Remote::Driver for Javascript that loads page later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, perl, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate login into 
https://strade.sharekhan.com

```
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
$driver->get("https://strade.sharekhan.com/");
```

I'm able to successfully open the firefox browser and fetch the page.
But the input elements aren't visible.

```
my $page_source = $driver->get_page_source();

$driver->find_element('emailLoginId')->send_keys("abcdefg");
```

The login section seems to be inside a separate class item,whose html source appears in the browser debugger,but when trying via selenium,the class item is empty.
I only know basic Javascript/jQuery... kindly help me out,what is it that I'm missing

```
my $login_element = $driver->find_element_by_class('loginresponsive');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this with [Selenium::Chrome](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Chrome) and it seems to work fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Chrome;
# Enter your driver path here. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/
#  for download instructions
my $driver_path = '/home/hakon/chromedriver/chromedriver';
my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new( binary => $driver_path );
$driver->get("https://strade.sharekhan.com/");
$driver->find_element_by_name('emailLoginId')->send_keys("abcdefg");
sleep 45;
```

Screen shot taken while sleeping (see last line in code above):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue was not related to firefox,but using `find_element_by_name`. Now I'm able to progress to the next screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can always wait for it to show up.

The following was written for Selenium::Chrome, but it demonstrates a portable principle.

```
use constant POLL_INTERVAL => 0.1;

use Time::HiRes qw( sleep time );

sub wait_for {
   my ($xpath, $max_wait) = @_;
   my $wait_until = time() + $max_wait;
   while (1) {
      if ( my $nodes = nf_find_elements($xpath) ) {
         return wantarray ? @$nodes : $nodes->[0];
      }

      my $time_left = $wait_until -  time();
      return () if $time_left <= 0;

      sleep(min($time_left, POLL_INTERVAL));
   }
}


# Version of `find_elements` that doesn't die (non-fatal) when the element isn't found.
sub nf_find_elements {
   my $nodes;
   if (!eval {
      $nodes = $web_driver->find_elements(@_);
      return 1;  # No exception.
   }) {
      return undef if $@ =~ /Unable to locate element|An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters/;
      die($@);
   }

   return wantarray ? @$nodes : $nodes;
}
```

Example usage:

```
my $node = wait_for('//some/path', 4.0)   # Wait up to 4s
   or die("Login was unsuccessful.\n");
```

---

Time::HiRes's `sleep` doesn't get interrupted by signals, so I used the following to make my Ctrl-C handler responsive:

```
use Time::HiRes qw( );

use constant SLEEP_INTERVAL => 0.1;

# Hi-res sleep that gives signal handlers a chance to run.
use subs qw( sleep );
sub sleep {
   if (!$_[0]) {
      Time::HiRes::sleep(SLEEP_INTERVAL) while 1;
      return;  # Never reached.
   }

   my $sleep_until = time() + $_[0];
   while (1) {
      my $time_left = $sleep_until - Time::HiRes::time();
      return if $time_left <= 0;

      Time::HiRes::sleep(min($time_left, SLEEP_INTERVAL));
   }
}
```

Make sure not to import `sleep` from Time::HiRes.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have `$driver->pause(1000)` and `sleep(2)` during/before clicking.

Comment: That's just an inefficient version of what I posted. It always waits the full 2 s, whereas mine only waits as long as needed (with a configurable granularity I set to 100 ms).

Comment: Yeah,I get that. But as of now,I'm running on a Windows laptop & would prefer to reduce CPU usage/number of system calls.

Comment: If your running of of battery, then I guess. But 100 ms is an eternity for a computer